# DIfficulty in proguard-ing javafx application

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, proguard

I have a javafx application which used to run fine with proguard.

However, after adding xerial-sqlite to my application, proguard still works fine however I encounter the following error while running using the **java -jar program.jar** command:

```
18:31:42,161 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [dailyRollingFileAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
18:31:42,161 |-INFO in k.a - End of configuration.
18:31:42,161 |-INFO in j.a@44a0093e - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
2017-Aug-13 18:31:42.287 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR B.c - No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:merchant.db 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:merchant.db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at B.e.<init>(SQLiteDataSource.java:52)
    at B.e.a(SQLiteDataSource.java:61)
    at com.datasoft.pay365.merchant.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Instantiation of the sqlite connection:

```
protected SQLiteDataSource() {
        connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:merchant.db");
            this.createTable();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I really need to be able to run this sqlite version of my application. How do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the driver using the current classloader?

```
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

If yes, are your library jars included in your java call or in same folder as your javafx jar or customly classloaded to be accessible by your main code?

Comment: No, I'm using [this library] (https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) here. Upon adding the sqlite jdbc jar file into the same folder, it seems to run. Since the library manages the 
`Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");`
I didn't make any such call. It hasn't been customly loaded either (apart from the fact that I'm using maven, if it helps).
I might sound inexperienced and I am. Can you suggest how to fix such problems?